# How to calculate sum of different table which separated by years and what is the best data model to support ? Power BI

Tags: sum, powerbi

**Desire Result**

Choose **year** from Slicer , return **sum** result of **Scorecard** .
[image]
**Problems**
No single measure can be putted in scorecard and to apply for calculating all tables while year is selected by slicer .

```
e.g.
sum(table20[Score])
sum(table21[Score])
sum(table22[Score])
```

- Have to **avoid append table** as each tables of a single year contains over millions of rows.
- All tables are imported from power bi dataflow **without using Direct Query**.

**Data**

```
table20
YEAR    GEO Type    Score
2020    Asia    A   1
2020    Africa  A   2.5
2020    CentralAfrica   A   0
2020    Europe  A   0
2020    MiddleEast  A   0
2020    America A   1.5
table21
YEAR    GEO Type    Score
2021    Asia    A   3
2021    Africa  A   2
2021    CentralAfrica   A   6
2021    Europe  A   1
2021    MiddleEast  A   2
2021    America A   8
table22
YEAR    GEO Type    Score
2022    Asia    A   4
2022    Africa  A   0
2022    CentralAfrica   C   3
2022    Europe  C   4
2022    MiddleEast  A   1
2022    America A   5
```

**Relationship**
Calendar table link those tables .

```
Calander = CALENDAR(DATE(2020,1,1),DATE(2022,12,31))
```

[image]

**What is the best way to achieve this without appends to be a larger dataset ?**
Not sure aggregation based on "imported table" can help on the performance ?
Please advise if my concept is basically wrong like append table cannot be avoided .e.t.c.

Comment: You are making a mistake. Combining all these tables into one is the only correct data model. It's also the most efficient - you current design will be much, much slower than the combined table, because Power BI stores data as columns, not as tables, and it's optimized for the data stored in columns. Besides, millions of records is a rather small data set - PBI can handle billions.

Comment: RADO thanks for your explanations . Hence I should return for the original model to append 3 of them without tick "enable load" . So we have no solution to lighten small data as millions rows ? as 3 of them are based on dataflow as "Imported mode" , hot and cold data approaches based on SQL query cannot apply on this situation .

Comment: PBI allows partitioning and incremental data refresh: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview